# Calculate confidence that a population is evenly distributed between several values

Tags: confidence-interval, chi-squared-test

I apologize if this is too basic, or is poorly worded. It's been a long time since I sat in a stats class, and I'm having trouble figuring out how to search for what I need.

I have a system that generates results of 7 different types. It could be modeled as a bag of infinite size, filled with balls of 7 different colors. I have a sample set of 97 results, and they are distributed among the 7 types: 11, 17, 9, 10, 17, 19, 14.

It is my theory that the likelihood of getting a result of any one of the 7 types is 1:7, i.e. the results are expected to be evenly distributed among the 7 different types.

How can I calculate a confidence value to support or refute my hypothesis?

Comment: You can't prove that it's correct (since at some given sample size slightly unequal proportions will be indistinguishable from equal proportions under random sampling -- sample variation will exceed any sufficiently small effect size) -- failure to reject the null doesn't show equality. You can however, hope to show they're unequal if they're sufficiently different or that the probabilities are closer to equal than some predetermined equivalence bound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can treat this as an equivalence testing problem. What you want to do is estimate an interval for each group then check if that interval is within a given range. Without sampling error, you would expect each group to have 1/7 as proportions exactly. But with sampling error, this would not be the case. As your sample size increases, the sampling error will reduce. So because of sampling error, you should decide a-priori what the acceptable range is.

To elaborate, $1/7 \approx 14.29\%$. You can decide a-priori that the acceptable error is. For my example, I'll go with $2.5\%$, so $14.29\%\pm 2.5\%$ is our range. If the confidence interval for the frequency of each group is within this range, then we have equivalence. If the confidence exceeds this range, then we do not have equivalence.

Here's a complete example. Since you mention that you have a huge sample size, I will assume a total sample size of 3500. This means we expect each group to have a frequency of 500. In R:

```R
set.seed(12345) # For reproducibility
n <- 3500 # Sample size
# The syntax below generates counts for 7 groups that should have equal frequencies
dat <- as.data.frame(table(sample(1:7, size = n, replace = TRUE)))
dat$Group <- LETTERS[1:7] # Give group names
dat # What the data look like:
#   Var1 Freq Group
# 1    1  486     A
# 2    2  490     B
# 3    3  488     C
# 4    4  509     D
# 5    5  500     E
# 6    6  534     F
# 7    7  493     G
```

We see that the frequencies are pretty close to 500 for each group. Next, we run our Poisson regression using the groups as predictors of the counts:

```R
mod <- glm(Freq ~ 0 + Group, poisson)
```

In this model, I predicted frequencies using `0 + Group` which has the effect of removing the intercept. So we get an expected log frequency per group. For the results:

```R
mod
# 
# Call:  glm(formula = Freq ~ 0 + Group, family = poisson, data = dat)
# 
# Coefficients:
# GroupA  GroupB  GroupC  GroupD  GroupE  GroupF  GroupG  
#  6.186   6.194   6.190   6.232   6.215   6.280   6.201  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 7 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
# Null Deviance:        36520 
# Residual Deviance: 1.332e-13  AIC: 70.37
```

If we exponentiate any of those coefficients, we will obtain the original frequency for that group. Next, we obtain confidence intervals on these expected log frequencies:

```R
(lims <- confint(mod))
# Waiting for profiling to be done...
#           2.5 %   97.5 %
# GroupA 6.095964 6.273814
# GroupB 6.104535 6.281658
# GroupC 6.100258 6.277744
# GroupD 6.144296 6.318080
# GroupE 6.125654 6.300996
# GroupF 6.194362 6.364028
# GroupG 6.110917 6.287500
```

Let's re-organize the `lims` object so the lower limit is the first column, estimate is in the middle, and upper limit is last. Also exponentiate to place everything back on the frequency scale:

```R
(lims <- as.data.frame(exp(cbind(ll = lims[, 1], est = coef(mod), ul = lims[, 2]))))
#              ll est       ul
# GroupA 444.0618 486 530.4970
# GroupB 447.8844 490 534.6744
# GroupC 445.9730 488 532.5858
# GroupD 466.0514 509 554.5074
# GroupE 457.4440 500 545.1148
# GroupF 489.9787 534 580.5801
# GroupG 450.7518 493 537.8070
```

We now have our limits. And so we want all these values to be between:

```R
(range <- 1 / 7 + c(-.025, 0, .025))
# [1] 0.1178571 0.1428571 0.1678571
range * n
# [1] 412.5 500.0 587.5
```

We can plot these results to see how well we're faring:

```R
library(ggplot2) # plotting library

lims$Group <- dat$Group
notes <- "Vertical dashed lines are lower bound, expectation and upper bound going from left to right"

ggplot(lims, aes(Group, est)) + geom_point() +
  geom_linerange(aes(ymin = ll, ymax = ul)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = range * n, linetype = 2) +
  coord_flip() + theme_bw() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 700, 50), range * n)) +
  labs(caption = notes)
```

[image]

In this example, all the confidence intervals are within the bounds. So we have equivalence. This [image from the Wikipedia article on equivalence testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_test#/media/File:Equivalence_Test.png) and the remainder of the article is a decent explainer of what we're looking for.

You can reduce the interval to say $\pm.01\%$ or even smaller if your sample size gets really large and you want tighter bounds. Reducing the bounds below what you even desire is a good idea because of multiple hypothesis testing issues. Hope this helps. All of my old answer now resides here: https://privatebin.net/?6e86161aa7d24515#U+EY4sxTAvqsPfTW2PufoTnBYG/pV/U6GKYe3x6MvnA=

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough and clear explanation. I appreciate the time that you took to describe the analysis in detail.

Comment: Actually, I've been thinking about this a bit more... I'm confused by "your sample size − 1". I was expecting something related to the fact that I have 97 "samples". This seems to imply that I would be no more confident of my results if I had millions of results from the system. I would expect that I could define the distribution of results with 100% confidence if I had an infinite number of results, or that my histogram would asymptotically approach the real distribution as my result set approaches infinity. But I don't see anything like this in the equations you have here. Am I wrong?

Comment: The first part of your question is easy. If you look at the formula for G, at larger samples, G gets much bigger. So the sample size is accounted for despite the degrees of freedom remaining constant. The second part of your question is much more complicated. See @Glen_b's comment on your original post. I was not completely transparent with my answer. Since you actually want to retain the null hypothesis, traditional hypothesis testing is not for you unless you modify it to an equivalence test as suggested in that comment. I'll update my answer if I get some time.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, you're right. Playing around with the numbers a bit in R, I can see that the G value, and the resulting p value, change based on number of samples, just as you say. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something subtle in the question, this sounds like a classic example where a chi-square goodness-of-fit would be applied.

```
Observed = c(11, 17, 9, 10, 17, 19, 14)

chisq.test(Observed)

   # Chi-squared test for given probabilities
   # 
   # X-squared = 6.701, df = 6, p-value = 0.3494
```

In this case, the *p*-value is greater than our threshold (of, say, 0.05), so we don't have good evidence that the distribution varies from the uniform.

Another way to look at it would be to construct the 95% confidence intervals for the multinomial proportions.

```
library(DescTools)

MultinomCI(Observed, conf.level=0.95, method="sisonglaz")

   #             est     lwr.ci    upr.ci
   # [1,] 0.11340206 0.03092784 0.2148456
   # [2,] 0.17525773 0.09278351 0.2767012
   # [3,] 0.09278351 0.01030928 0.1942270
   # [4,] 0.10309278 0.02061856 0.2045363
   # [5,] 0.17525773 0.09278351 0.2767012
   # [6,] 0.19587629 0.11340206 0.2973198
   # [7,] 0.14432990 0.06185567 0.2457734
```

Here, *est* is the proportion of observations in each of the 7 types and *lwr.ci* and *upr.ci* delineate the confidence intervals.  In this case each confidence interval includes 0.143 (1/7), which suggests none of the types is likely to deviate from that 1/7 proportion.

Comment: Originally, my answer was along the same lines https://privatebin.net/?6e86161aa7d24515#U+EY4sxTAvqsPfTW2PufoTnBYG/pV/U6GKYe3x6MvnA=. I developed chi-square and also motivated it as Poisson regression. But OP actually wants to retain the null hypothesis. There are always differences in samples and at large enough n, there will be power to detect such differences. So I recommended some kind of equivalence testing.